# When encrypting strings, does it make sense to append/prepend something to avoid reverse engineering the crypter?

Tags: encryption, encoding

Let's say I want to encrypt some string ... say the user email address.  In this situation is it a good idea to, for example, to encrypt email address as the string:

```
"sometext:" + email
```

(and when decrypting, removing the extra prefix)

instead of just the email address itself?  My concern is that if we expose the encrypted string somewhere, someone may be able to generate enough encrypted strings (and their plain text versions) and be able to engineer encrypted email addresses on their own.

Thoughts?

Comment: Well, you've just described [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). ) It should be used, but salt alone cannot solve problems of the weak (or weakly implemented) encryption algorithms.

Comment: ah yes, but it looks like a salt is usually randomly generated.  Does using the same salt every time give protection?  I would assume that if the user doesn't know what the (static) salt value is, it would be as useful as using a random salt ... is that not correct?

Comment: I don't think you've just described a salt, if only because a salt is part of a key derivation function, and is not part of a encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This technique is already known as [salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_%28cryptography%29) and pretty common.

If you keep the salt secret, mix it with the input and feed that into a cryptographic hash function you **should** be safe. Nevertheless, you should make sure what you're doing, especially when doing crypto! Example salting using sha1:

```
saltedHash = sha1(salt + input)
```

You can now store the resulting hash. If you need to compare a given input to the stored one, you do the same procedure and compare the salted hashes.

Sitenote: If you're using this for a [`MAC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) you should not proceed further without reading about Secret Prefix/Suffix Hashes and practicing crypto.

Comment: I think that Peter was asking for encryption, not hashing.

Comment: This didn't make sense to me, as he talks about others generating encrypted texts. This would only be possible if the 'others' have the key. And with the attacker having the key, the whole thing is pointless. So I was going for hashing.

Answer (score 1):

Attacking an encrypted cyphertext where you know all or part of the plaintext is called a [known plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack).  Modern cyphers, such as AES, are proof against such an attack.  You can add extra salt if you wish, but it will not really increase security if you are using a good cypher modern like AES.

Comment: +1 but maybe add a warning about using an IV/NONCE, otherwise you could guess the name (the most common first block of ciphertext would be the name)

Comment: An IV or Nonce is required for modes like CTR or CBC.  If the encryptor is using ECB mode then they deserve to have their data read.

Answer (score 1):

AES or any other secure cipher is protected against plain text attacks. However, if used incorrectly, then you can still retrieve data from them. E.g. when you use a stream cipher mode, then you can retrieve the plain text if you don't use a unique NONCE. Another common way of retrieving information is simply looking at the size of a cipher text.

If you use a more common mode such as CBC encryption then you should use an IV that is indistinguishable from a random number (to the attacker). You may then prepend that IV to the cipher text. If you don't, then an attacker can simply compare the first bytes of the ciphertext against the other ciphertexts. If these are identical then the attacker is probably seeing a common name. The IV protects against this.

Reading the text again, what you are trying to achieve is some protection against somebody else sending you a ciphertext, which could be interpreted as a valid mail after decryption. This can be avoided by adding integrity protection using a MAC or HMAC (using another key) or by using mode that supplies integrity protection such as GCM. This would protect you against such practices, but not against replay attacks. You need to encrypt or verify some sort of unique token (sender + sequence number) to achieve protection against that scenario.

Adding just that static piece of text won't help against any scenario, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends from the algorithm you are going to use. If you use a weak one, yes whatever string you might append it will still be crackable.

If you use a very strong encryption mechanism this will add a lot to your security.